# TypeError: schematype.castForQueryWrapper is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport-local

I am working on the registration module of a website which requires a mongoose find query to be made inside passport.local , return an error if user already exist and if everything goes well save the user information to the db. However, find query returns "TypeError: schematype.castForQueryWrapper is not a function" error.

**lib - authentication.js**

```
    passport.use('local-signup', new localStrategy(
    {
      usernameField    : 'username',
      passwordField    : 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },

    function(req, username, password, done) {

      // asynchronous
      // userModel.findOne wont fire unless data is sent back
      process.nextTick(function() {

        var recaptcha = nconf.get('recaptcha');

        if (recaptcha && req.recaptcha.error) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'The recaptcha could not be verified.'));
        }

        // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
        // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
        userModel.findOne({ 'local.username': username }, function(err, user) {

          // if there are any errors, return the error
          if (err)
          console.log(err);
            // return done(err);

           // check to see if there's already a user with that email
           if (user) {
             return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'This user already exists.'));
           } else {

             // if there is no user with that email
             // create the user
             var newUser = new userModel();

             // set the user's local credentials
             newUser.local.username = username;
             newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);
             newUser.data.email = req.body.email;
             newUser.data.phone = req.body.phone;

             // save the user
             newUser.save(function(err) {
               if (err)
                 throw err;
               return done(null, newUser);
             });
           }
        });
      });
    })
);
```

**route - authentication.js**

```
  router.post('/register', middleware.recaptcha.verify, auth.register);
```

**controller main.js**

```
main.register = function (req, res, next) {
  var data = {
    error:  req.flash('error')[ 0 ],
    recaptcha: req.recaptcha
  };

  res.render('register', data);
};
```

**model user.js**

```
    /*
 global module,
 require
 */

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    nconf = require('nconf'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    username: String,
    password: String
  },

  settings: {
    showLastAuctions: Boolean,
    useGravatarImage: { type: Boolean, default: false }
  },

  data: {
    admin:        { type: Boolean, default: false },
    email:        String,
    phone:        String,
    profileImg:   String,
    realname:     String,
    birthday:     String,
    registerDate: Date,
    status:       String,

    paymentUnits: Number,

    auctions: [ {
      id:       String,
      name:     String,
      date:     Date,
      endPrice: String
    } ],

    connections: [ {
      remoteAddress: String,
      hostname:      String,
      location:      String,
      lastSeen:      Date
    } ]
  }
}//,{
//  collection: 'users'
//}
);


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError: schematype.castForQueryWrapper is not a function
    at cast (/var/www/marduk/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:269:32)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (/var/www/marduk/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3302:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (/var/www/marduk/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1292:10)
    at model.Query.Query._findOne (/var/www/marduk/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1504:8)
    at /var/www/marduk/node_modules/kareem/index.js:250:8
    at /var/www/marduk/node_modules/kareem/index.js:23:7
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Can you pleae give me a direction on how to fix the issue?

Mongodb version 3.2.18
Mongoose version 4.13.7
Node version v8.9.3

Comment: From my understanding of this error, an object has some metada that may not be accepted by Mongoose. The simplest workaround I found so far is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newUser))` and this will get you a clean object ready to be saved. Another possible reason for this error is that your newUser structure does not match the data model

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else with this issue, the problem for me was a mongoose version conflict between two parts of a project.

I was importing an internal library that made use of mongoose, and it was using mongoose version 7. The project the helper was imported into was using mongoose 6 though. Making sure they both used the same version resolved it for me (I believe I upgraded both to 7).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I had the exact same issue. I checked my package.json after reading your answer. Both micro-services had different versions (6 and 7)